# Mysterious component marking

Tags: power, capacitor, resistors, ratings, component-values

I have stumbled across this component which I’m trying to replace. It has a rating of `22mΩF`.

It looks to be a resistor but I am confused as to why there is an ‘`F`’ in the rating as this indicates a measurement of capacitance.

[image: component]

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out in the comments, the `F` is a code that specifies the tolerance: `F` means 1%.

So `22mΩF` identifies a 1% 22 mΩ resistor.

See [tolerance code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKM_code#Tolerance_code) on Wikipedia for a complete table of codes.

Two other sources that explain the marking of (SMD) components are:

- [SMD Resistors: Codes, Size, Testing, Tolerance and Selection](https://www.utmel.com/blog/categories/resistor/smd-resistors-codes-size-testing-tolerance-and-selection)
- [Resistor Colour Code and Resistor Tolerances Explained](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_2.html)